# R arrange only if column takes on a specific value

Tags: r

How to arrange a column/df only if a column takes on a specific value. Consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                 b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 c = c(0, 0.4, 0.3, 0, 0.2, -0.3, 0, -0.2))


# I only want to arrange the df (e.g. ascending) if c != 0:

  a b    c
1 1 1  0.0
2 1 2  0.3
3 1 3  0.4
4 2 4  0.0
5 2 5 -0.2
6 2 6  0.3
7 3 7  0
8 3 8 -0.2
```

Comment: Provide more information on how do you want to arrange data?

Comment: I think the last 2 values should be -0.3 and 0.2.

Comment: ohh, sorry. I forgot the ascending bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c == 0)) %>%
  arrange(c != 0, c, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

#      a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1   0  
#2     1     3   0.3
#3     1     2   0.4
#4     2     4   0  
#5     2     6  -0.3
#6     2     5   0.2
```

Comment: Works on the toy data. My data is similar, except that the length of c differs across a. So dplyr throws an error: `order(c != 0, c, .by_group = TRUE)` length of the arguments differ

Comment: Try with `arrange(!c %in% 0, c, .by_group = TRUE)`

Comment: Does not seem to work, Ive adopted the above example to the extended case of different lengths

Comment: I still get the expected output shown in your post using my answer. (except that you still have -0.3 and 0.2 interchanged).

Comment: yea, some package clash caused the glitch, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand your question correctly you simply want the dataframe, but only with the rows included if c is not 0?

```
df <- df[df$c!=0,]
```